# Timeline of atmospheric model resolution

Tags: models, nwp, reference-request

I'm looking for a graph of improvements in spatial resolution for any atmospheric model (such as the [UK Met Office Unified Model](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/research/modelling-systems/unified-model) or [ECMWF IFS](http://www.ecmwf.int/en/research/modelling-and-prediction)).  Ideally it would include a range of historical model versions and perhaps forecasts for future model resolutions.

Comment: Do you mean global atmospheric models for numerical weather prediction? Or climate model configurations? Or limited area configurations? Deterministic or ensemble ensemble setups?

Comment: Any of those are fine, I just wanted a figure to illustrate the fact that model resolutions have, in general, been increasing over time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Europe is looking nicer and nicer every year ([source](http://www.nap.edu/read/13430/chapter/7#64)):

[image: Improvements in climate model resolution and process representation over time.]

This is a little bit out of date, since AR5 is already out - the dates for the first 4 IPCC reports were:

- IPCC First Assessment Report, 1990
- IPCC Second Assessment Report, 1995
- IPCC Third Assessment Report, 2001
- IPCC Fourth Assessment Report, 2007
- IPCC Fifth Assessment Report, 2014

And an updated image for AR5 looks like this (both of these are AR5 model resolutions) ([source](http://www.climatechange2013.org/images/report/WG1AR5_Chapter01_FINAL.pdf), p145):

[image: Improvements in modelling resolution in AR5]

And that same PDF has another representation of increasing complexity, where cylinder height indicates complexity ([source](http://www.climatechange2013.org/images/report/WG1AR5_Chapter01_FINAL.pdf), p144):

[image]

Comment: Superb figures, thank you.  The fact that they show how small scale steeper slopes are also resolved at higher resolutions was also something that I wanted to illustrate.